# Video upload with FacebookSDK

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, video, sdk

I'm trying to upload a video file from iOS to Facebooks GraphAPI.
Sadly it's not working as expected. Although [This](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/video-uploads) says my local .mov should be supported, im getting the following error:

```
Error: Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=8 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.facebook.sdk.core error 8.)" UserInfo=0x161a2f30 {com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorGraphErrorCode=352, com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorParsedJSONResponseKey={
body =     {
    error =         {
        code = 352;
        message = "(#352) Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support.";
        type = OAuthException;
    };
};
code = 400;
}, 
com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorHTTPStatusCodeKey=400,
com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=(#352) Sorry, the video file you selected is in a format that we don't support., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKGraphRequestErrorCategoryKey=0}
```

My code is as follows:

```
//Outlet 4 picking movie file from PhotoLibrary        
@IBAction func shareVideo(sender: UIButton) {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary){
            println("Video capture")
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
            imagePicker.mediaTypes = [kUTTypeMovie]
            self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }


func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
        println(info)

        //Stoping the ImagePickerView
        imagePicker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)

    var videoDatei : NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: info[UIImagePickerControllerMediaURL] as! NSURL)!

    var params : NSDictionary = ["source" : videoDatei ]

    var token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString



    var videoRequest : FBSDKGraphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me/videos", parameters: params as [NSObject : AnyObject], tokenString: token, version: nil, HTTPMethod: "POST")
    videoRequest.startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

        if ((error) != nil)
        {
            // Process error
            println("Error: \(error)")

        }
        else
        {
            println(result)
        }
    })
}
```

FacebookSDK documentation doesn't give any example code for videoupload apart from

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
 @"source": @"{video-data}",
};
```

and sending the request, no information on {video-data} apart from "multipart/form-data" which i don't fully understand.

Info:
iOS 8.3
Swift
FacebookSDK v.4.1.0
FBSDK GraphAPI v.2.3

Thanks for all your time,
ROLF

Comment: Can you try also define the contentType parameter as @"video/quicktime" to see if it helps?